# Get content of an HTMLInputElement word document in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ms-word

I have an ms-word document as HTMLInputElement in my javascript. How do I get the full content of the file to save it as a Blob object and be able to retrieve it?

```
var file = document.getElementById('ms-word');
**var content = file.getcontentofthefile;**
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about the Office Web Apps API? Have you checked the documentation of the API for any way to do it?

Comment: Not really... I just want to save the file in my DB and my DB accepts blob objects only!

Comment: Great, but can you explain a bit what this `ms-word` element is? Is it `<input type=file>` and the user has simply picked a Word document?

Comment: Have you researched? Have you Googled 'getting content from input type file using javascript'? The first result seems to be helpful.

Comment: yes but I got only for HTML documents not ms-word...

Comment: This is the first result I get - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ - it even mentions Blob. You comment is unclear to me.

Comment: It mentions blob but it's unclear to me how you get this blob from the FileReader class...

Comment: Search for "blob" within the page, there are a lot of matches.

Comment: I think you didn't really understand... I have a file that I want to transform into a Blob object! The link you provided is a way to read either file or blob not to transform file INTO blob. Hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inputElement.files[0].slice(0, inputElement.files[0].size);`

Taken from http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/.